# Fade all the un-selected cells in excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, cells

I have a long table in Excel 2013 and it is very hard to read and focus on a specific cell. I want to know if there is any way to automatically fade all the un-selected cells?

By fade, I mean when I select a cell, the background and the font colors of all the un-selected cells change to white and when I don't select any cell, the font and background colors must be the predefined one.

I've tried the conditional formatting but it doesn't seem promising.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This seems like a simple question, but can you explain specifically what you mean by "fade"? Also, what have you researched and/or attempted so far?

Comment: Thanks. By fade, I mean when I select a cell, the background and the font colors of all the un-selected cells change to white and when I don't select any cell, the font and background colors must be the predefined one.

Comment: I've tried the conditional formatting but it doesn't seem promising..:(

Comment: This is not something Excel does natively. If it can be done, it will most likely have to be VBA. The challenge you face is that in Excel, there is  always a selected cell. Therefore, you statement "*when I don't select any cell*" is not likely to happen.

Comment: its 2017 can we do this guys? 

How to fade all cells except active row & header if any